# Importance sampling and Metropolis MC

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, sequential-monte-carlo

I am evaluating numerically integral
$$I(\theta) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 dx_4 \int_0^{+\infty} dy_1 dy_2 dy_3 dy_4 \prod_{k=0}^4\left[w_n(x_k)w_e(y_k)\right]F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4; \theta),$$
where
$$w_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},\\
w_e(y) = e^{-y},$$
i.e. the normal and the exponential distributions.

For now I am using the importance sampling, drawing multiple samples $(\mathbf{x}^{(j)}, \mathbf{y}^{(j)})$, and estimating the integral as
$$\hat{I} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N F(\mathbf{x}^{(j)}, \mathbf{y}^{(j)};\theta).$$
Obtaining precise results requires very large $N$ I suspect that it scales exponentially with the number of dimensions, i.e. at least $100^8$). I am therefore wondering: **would it be faster, if I use Metropolis Monte Carlo?**

For the background: I am using Python, so by implementing Metropolis I might use some of the advantages of vectorization implemented in lower level numpy routines.

Comment: Imho importance sampling in dimension 8 is unlikely to work off-the-shelf. A Metropolis-within-Gibbs strategy would somewhat scale better with the dimension if the target is not a product of independent Normal and Exponential densities. Since the integral is the quantity of interest, the target distribution should be similar to the product$$\prod_{k=0}^4\left[w_n(x_k)w_e(y_k)\right]F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4; \theta)$$i.e., involve $F$ as well.

Comment: I don't see how the importance sampling could be tuned here to work better.

Comment: My comment does not suggest to tune IS but to tune MH.